# Find various ways of allocating fruit to people

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
# Example 1
People = ["Terry", "Merry"]
Fruit = ["Apple","Grape","Peach"]

# Possible solutions:
[
  {"Terry"=>"Apple","Merry"=>"Grape"},
  {"Terry"=>"Apple","Merry"=>"Peach"},

  {"Terry"=>"Grape","Merry"=>"Apple"},
  {"Terry"=>"Grape","Merry"=>"Peach"},

  {"Terry"=>"Peach","Merry"=>"Apple"},
  {"Terry"=>"Peach","Merry"=>"Grape"},
]

# Example 2
People = ["Terry", "Merry", "Perry"]
Fruit = ["Apple","Grape"]

# Possible solutions:
[
  {"Terry"=>"Apple","Merry"=>"Grape","Perry"=>nil},
  {"Terry"=>"Apple","Merry"=>nil,"Perry"=>"Grape"},

  {"Terry"=>"Grape","Merry"=>"Apple","Perry"=>nil},
  {"Terry"=>"Grape","Merry"=>nil,"Perry"=>"Apple"},

  {"Terry"=>nil,"Merry"=>"Apple","Perry"=>"Grape"},
  {"Terry"=>nil,"Merry"=>"Grape","Perry"=>"Apple"},
]
```

**Stuck trying to solve this recursively (necessary for this exercise, though let me know if you don't think recursion is possible).**

I feel like basically I start by assigning a random person a fruit, and then add that to all possible solutions that arise from the smaller subset of assigning remaining people remaining fruit.

E.g., for Example 1, I assign Terry an Apple, and then aggregate that with the remaining possible options of what Merry can get (either Grape or Peach).

Then just repeat changing up the fruit assigned to the first random person (e.g., with Terry getting Grape then Peach, in Example 1).

I feel like this sounds so straightforward but I'm struggling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done recursively as follows.

```
def hmmm(people, fruit)
  adj_fruit = fruit + [nil]*([people.size-fruit.size, 0].max)
  recurse(adj_fruit).map { |a| people.zip(a).to_h }
end
```

```
def recurse(fruit_left, fruit_selected = [])
  return [fruit_selected + fruit_left] if fruit_left.size == 1
  fruit_left.each_with_object([]) do |f,a|
    recurse(fruit_left - [f], fruit_selected + [f]).each { |e| a << e }
  end
end
```

```
hmmm(["Terry", "Merry"], ["Apple", "Grape", "Peach"])
  #=> [{"Terry"=>"Apple", "Merry"=>"Grape"}, {"Terry"=>"Apple", "Merry"=>"Peach"},
  #    {"Terry"=>"Grape", "Merry"=>"Apple"}, {"Terry"=>"Grape", "Merry"=>"Peach"},
  #    {"Terry"=>"Peach", "Merry"=>"Apple"}, {"Terry"=>"Peach", "Merry"=>"Grape"}]
```

Here `adj_fruit #=> ["Apple", "Grape", "Peach"]`

```
hmmm(["Terry", "Merry", "Perry"], ["Apple", "Grape"])
  #=> [{"Terry"=>"Apple", "Merry"=>"Grape", "Perry"=>nil},
  #    {"Terry"=>"Apple", "Merry"=>nil,     "Perry"=>"Grape"},
  #    {"Terry"=>"Grape", "Merry"=>"Apple", "Perry"=>nil},
  #    {"Terry"=>"Grape", "Merry"=>nil,     "Perry"=>"Apple"},
  #    {"Terry"=>nil,     "Merry"=>"Apple", "Perry"=>"Grape"},
  #    {"Terry"=>nil,     "Merry"=>"Grape", "Perry"=>"Apple"}]
```

Here `adj_fruit #=> ["Apple", "Grape", nil]`.

---

We can see `map`'s receiver in `hmmm` by removing `.map { |a| people.zip(a).to_h }` from its last line.

```
def hmmm(people, fruit)
  adj_fruit = fruit + [nil]*([people.size-fruit.size, 0].max)
  recurse(adj_fruit)
end
```

```
hmmm(["Terry", "Merry"], ["Apple","Grape","Peach"])
  #=> [["Apple", "Grape", "Peach"], ["Apple", "Peach", "Grape"],
  #    ["Grape", "Apple", "Peach"], ["Grape", "Peach", "Apple"],
  #    ["Peach", "Apple", "Grape"], ["Peach", "Grape", "Apple"]]
```

---

A more conventional solution, such as the one following, would not employ recursion.

```
def hmmm(people, fruit)
  (fruit + [nil]*[people.size - fruit.size, 0].max).
    permutation(people.size).
    map { |a| people.zip(a).to_h }
end
```

This produces the same return values as those shown above for the recursive solution.

See [Array#permutation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-permutation) and [Enumerable#zip](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-zip).

Comment: always to the rescue thank you! if i may ask... when you say you don't know if this can be done with recursion, is there simply no implication, e.g., i don't know i haven't thought about it; or is there an implication that it's difficult, e.g., i don't know because it seems hard?  IF the latter, any insight on why it may be difficult? because conceptually it seems straightforward to me but i have been staring at my paper forever...

Comment: For anyone's future reference, `nil` definitely throws some wrenches in this... with the recursive method, `nil` undercounts (i have not explored why). with the non-recursive method, `nil` overcounts since `nil` is treated as a unique entry, the code reads `{"Terry"=>"apple","Merry"=>nil,"Perry"=>nil}` and `{"Terry"=>"apple","Perry"=>nil,"Merry"=>nil}` as 2 distinct solutions

Comment: Oh yes sorry I was testing with a new use case: `hmmm(["Terry", "Merry","Perry"], ["Apple"])`, this returns 2 possible solutions `[{"Terry"=>nil, "Merry"=>"Apple", "Perry"=>nil}, {"Terry"=>nil, "Merry"=>"Apple", "Perry"=>nil}]`. Again though not a big deal for this specific exercise

Comment: james, not a problem. I deleted my comment; you may wish to remove yours.

Answer (score 0):

If `len(people) <= len(fruit)`, then you can use

```
for pieces in itertools.permutations(fruit, len(people)):
    assign the pieces of fruit to the people in order
```

If `len(people) > len(fruit)`, then use

```
for eaters in itertools.permutations(people, len(fruit))
    assign the eaters to the fruit in order, and the others get nothing
```

I don't know how to combine the two separate cases into a single case

---

I now see that this was supposed to be solve recursively.  Misread the original.

Let's look  the possibilities for

assignment(people, fruit):

- If `len(people) == 0`, then you're done, with the empty solution.  (Not to be confused with no solution.)
- If `len(fruit) == 0`, then no one gets any fruit.  Again, this is an actual solution.
- If `len(people) <= len(fruit)`, then the first person gets some piece of fruit, appended onto all possible results of the remainder of the people getting the remainder of the fruit.
- If `len(people) > len(fruit)`, then either the first person does or doesn't get a piece of fruit, and recursively the rest of the people get whatever's left.

It's left as an exercise to you how to code this.

Comment: do you think this can be done wiht recursion

Comment: Oh sorry.  Didn't see the recursion part at the end. . . .

Answer (score 0):

For anyone's future reference, this was my answer using recursion.

NOTE that "nil" overcounts; since "nil" is treated as a unique entry, the code reads `{"Terry"=>"apple","Merry"=>"nil","Perry"=>"nil"}` and `{"Terry"=>"apple","Perry"=>"nil","Merry"=>"nil"}` as 2 distinct solutions. I did not investigate further because this isn't super realistic for the exercise that this is a part of.

I also didn't investigate further for same reason, but using string `"nil"` versus `nil` yielded different results

```
  def pure5(people, fruit, solution = [])
    people_count = people.size 
    fruit_count = fruit.size 
    diff = people_count - fruit_count
    diff.times { fruit << "nil" } if diff > 0 

    people.each do |p|
      fruit.each do |f|
        if people.size == 1
          obj = {}
          obj[p] = f
          solution << obj
        else
          partial_solution = pure5(people - [p], fruit - [f])
          partial_solution.each do |s|
            s[p] = f
          end    
          solution = solution + partial_solution
        end
      end
      return solution
    end
  end
```